# Make an <iframe> fill the <div> without changing the default dimensions of another element in the <div> using only CSS

Tags: html, css, iframe, flexbox

I was asked an interview question about CSS.
The problem is as follows.

There is a `<div>` with an `<img>` and an `<iframe>` in it, arranged vertically. The `<img>` has unknown default height and width, and **leave it as it is**. Changing the default dimension of `<img>`, no matter explicitly or implicitly, is not allowed. The `<div>` should have the same width as the `<img>` and be 100px high. The `<iframe>` should fill the remaining space in the `<div>` but not exceed its height.

Only use CSS and do not assume the image's default width and height, except for the fact that its height is less than 100px.

While I was unable to solve this problem during the interview, I am curious how it can be solved.

I've found a way to solve the problem when using `<div>` instead of `<iframe>`.

```css
.container {
    width: fit-content;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
.remaining {
    background-color: #bff3fd;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/200x50">
    <div class="remaining"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/y3ot6dzx/)

However, when I substitute the inner `<div>` with `<iframe>`, the parent `<div>` expands due to the `<iframe>` resulting in a change in the width of `<img>`. Moreover, the `<iframe>` overflows the parent `<div>`.

[JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/y3ot6dzx/1/)

Comment: `iframe` is a replaced inline element, and has default dimensions of 300px * 150px.  Since your container has `width: fit-content`, the iframe has no reason whatsoever, to shrink below those default 300px in width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `grid` here , where the grid is defined from the parent.
`Flex` builds a grid defined from the children.

Set your grid layout (here grid-template-rows is plenty enough), and resize iframe so it feets in the cell defined. Once the grid is defined, children are dispatched within the cells predefined.

examples:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.remaining {
  background-color: #bff3fd;
  /* here is a bit tricky, you need to overide default size that might be wider that image */
  width: 0;/* downsize it */
  min-width: 100%;/* make it use fullwidth */
  /* do it again for heights */
  height:0;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/200x20">
    <iframe src="https://example.com" class="remaining"></iframe>
</div>
another one with different size
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/240x50">
    <iframe src="https://example.com" class="remaining"></iframe>
</div>
```

layout set via `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;` where :

- `auto` set the row height from the content it holds
- `1fr` set the row's height with the remaining space.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use grid instead. It was helpful. However, I noticed that the current code snippet still allows the iframe to overflow the container on Chromium.  https://i.imgur.com/5H2rH99.png (It works perfectly on Firefox.) Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @Allen snippet updated : sizing height via the same method than width's  *0 but 100%* ;)